# Uploading Image to Cloudinary React & Express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I want to do the following:

```
1. Setup a Form where a user can upload images/text
2. Send form data over to express server via POST API
3. Receive form data in express and upload to cloudinary
4. Get cloudinary callback with url for image
5. Save rest of form data + cloudinary_image_url to database
```

I have completed step 1:

```
render(){
    return (
        <form onSubmit={this.handleCreate.bind(this)}>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Location" ref="location"/>
          <textarea placeholder="Description" ref="description"/>
          <input type="file" ref="image"/>
          <button>Add</button>
          {this.renderError()}
        </form>
    )
  }

  handleCreate(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    const location = this.refs.location;
    const description = this.refs.description;
    const image = this.refs.image;
    const validateInput = this.validateInput(location.value, description.value, image.value);

    if (validateInput) {
      this.setState({error: validateInput});
      return;
    }

    this.setState({error:null});
    this.props.createMemory(location.value, description.value, image.files[0]);

  }
```

Basically, I am using React Flux to handle the api call. Once the the `add` button is pressed, my code will trigger the `createMemory` function which will trigger an action that will call an API function:

```
export function createMemory(location, description, image) {
  axios.post('http://localhost:3000/uploads', {
    location,
    description,
    image
  }).then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
}
```

Now the `location` and `description` can be easily passed through but i am having trouble with passing the image. I understand that I need to use some sort of multi-data library such as `multer` to process the image.

Now in my backend express server I have:

var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' });

```
app.post('/upload', upload.single('image'), async (req, res) => {
    try {
        console.log(req.file);

    } catch (err) {
        res.sendStatus(400);
    }
})
```

Now I am supposed to have `req.file` be the `image` file but I get an `undefined...`. I know this is a long question but what am i doing wrong?

Comment: I've face-off the same problem and my approach is send data to server by `FormData`.